# Response validation failed: failed schema validation when returning 500 status

Tags: node.js, validation, swagger

I am using nodejs and swagger for my api. I need to send 500 status if something goes wrong. But when I do so I get this error `Response validation failed: failed schema validation`

Here is code for api (removed extra stuff)

```
function getAllBoards(req, res) {
    ...
    if (error)
        return res.status(500).json({ message: "Error" });
    return res.status(200).json(results);
```

Here is my swagger configuration

```
  /get_all_boards:
    # our controller name
    x-swagger-router-controller: elasticsearch
    get:
      operationId: getAllBoards
      description: get the list of boards
      # define the type of response for Success "200" and Error
      responses:
        "200":
          description: Success
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/GetBoardsListResponse"
        default:
          description: Error
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/ErrorResponse"
```

Error response scheme

```
ErrorResponse:
    required:
      - message
    properties:
      message:
        type: string
```

Note that if I return 200 status then I dont get any error, but when I send 500 as response I get the error.

Comment: Can you also post the `ErrorResponse` schema?

Comment: @Helen updated,

Comment: `"I need to send 500 status"` - does it work if you change the `default` response to `"500"` in the spec?